# Can't add more than one quantity on my product in cart on multistore magento

Tags: php, magento

I'm on magento 1.7, in a multistore configuration.

Here is my problem : in the product view, if I put a quantity superior of 1 for my product, it adds the product to the cart, but the quantity displayed in the cart is still at 1.
If I put 10, I click on the add to cart button, and in my cart I will have quantity at 1 for the product, without a warning or error message.

Due to my multistore configuration, I had to change my addtocart button code because it wasn't working.

```
    <button type="button" title="<?php echo $buttonTitle ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"><?php echo $buttonTitle ?></button>
```

to

```
    <button type="button" title="<?php echo $buttonTitle ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><?php echo $buttonTitle ?></button>
```

Any help, please ?
Thanks

Here is the all addtocart.phtml code :

```
    <?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
     <?php $buttonTitle = $this->__('Add to Cart'); ?>
      <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
       <div class="add-to-cart">
        <?php if(!$_product->isGrouped()): ?>
         <label for="qty"><?php echo $this->__('Qty:') ?></label>
         <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo $this->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" />
        <?php endif; ?>
        <button type="button" title="<?php echo $buttonTitle ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><?php echo $buttonTitle ?></button>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('', true, true) ?>
     </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Can you post all of addtocart.phtml

Comment: @Rob yes I just have modified my post. The code is here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem.

From my exception.log file, it was a cache_dir problem. The system puts data in cache and session on the server to make the post request, and in the cache directory (most likely "tmp").

Like I am on a multistore configuration, each substores was trying to write datas in the cache directory in his own store directory at root. And there were no cache directory in each store directory.

So I create one for each of my store and it works !
Problem solved